# How to create dynamic router for nested items in a sidebar with multilevel dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, react-router, sidebar

This is my code currently but the path is not dynamic, everytime when there is a new section in the dropdown I have to hard code the path, is there anyway that I can write a function to auto generate those paths?
(The first one is generating the multilevel sidebar, the second file is the router, and the third file is the content in the pages when you click on a section in the sidebar)

```
import React from "react";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import * as IoIcons from "react-icons/io";

export const SidebarData = [
  {
    label: "Vertical App",
    path: "/verticalapp",
    icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
    id: 1,
    branches: [
      {
        label: "Weather App",
        path: "/verticalapp/weatherapp",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 2,
        branches: [],
      },
      {
        label: "Occupancy App",
        path: "/verticalapp/occupancyapp",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 3,
        branches: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Company",
    path: "/company",
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
    id: 4,
    branches: [
      {
        label: "Reseller",
        path: "/company/reseller",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 5,
        branches: [
          {
            label: "Client 1",
            path: "/company/reseller/client1",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 6,
            branches: [
              {
                label: "Client 11",
                path: "/company/reseller/client11",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 7,
                branches: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: "Client 2",
            path: "/company/reseller/client2",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 8,
            branches: [
              {
                label: "Client 21",
                path: "/company/reseller/client21",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 9,
                branches: [],
              },
              {
                label: "Client 22",
                path: "/company/reseller/client22",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 10,
                branches: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "Client",
        path: "/company/client",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 11,
        branches: [
          {
            label: "Client 3",
            path: "/company/client/client3",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 12,
            branches: [],
          },
          {
            label: "Client 4",
            path: "/company/client/client4",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 13,
            branches: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "Consumer",
        path: "/company/consumer",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 14,
        branches: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  
  {
    label: "Contact Us",
    path: "/contactus",
    icon: <IoIcons.IoMdHelpCircle />,
    id: 20,
    branches: [],
  },
];
```

```
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import VerticalApp from './pages/VerticalApp';
//import { Company, Reseller, Client, Consumer, Client1, Client2 } from './pages/Company';
import {Company} from './pages/Company';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Sidebar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/verticalapp' exact component={VerticalApp} />
        <Route path='/company' exact component={Company} />
        {/* <Route path='/company/:label' component={Company} /> */}
        {/* <Route path='/company/reseller' exact component={Reseller} />
        <Route path='/company/client' exact component={Client} />
        <Route path='/company/consumer' exact component={Consumer} />
        <Route path='/company/reseller/client1' exact component={Client1} />
        <Route path='/company/reseller/client2' exact component={Client2} /> */}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

export const Company = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Reseller = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company/Reseller</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Client = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company/Client</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Consumer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company/Consumer</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Client1 = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company/Reseller/Client1</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Client2 = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports">
      <h1>Company/Reseller/Client2</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add route props to the `sidebarData` and recursively build an array of routes.

Example:

```
const sidebarData = [
  {
    label: "Vertical App",
    path: "/verticalapp",
    icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
    id: 1,
    routeProps: {
      render: () => <h1>Vertical App</h1>
    },
    branches: [
      {
        label: "Weather App",
        path: "/verticalapp/weatherapp",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 2,
        branches: []
      },
      {
        label: "Occupancy App",
        path: "/verticalapp/occupancyapp",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 3,
        branches: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Company",
    path: "/company",
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
    id: 4,
    routeProps: {
      component: Company
    },
    branches: [
      {
        label: "Reseller",
        path: "/company/reseller",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 5,
        routeProps: {
          component: Reseller
        },
        branches: [
          {
            label: "Client 1",
            path: "/company/reseller/client1",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 6,
            routeProps: {
              component: Client1
            },
            branches: [
              {
                label: "Client 11",
                path: "/company/reseller/client11",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 7,
                branches: []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: "Client 2",
            path: "/company/reseller/client2",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 8,
            routeProps: {
              component: Client2
            },
            branches: [
              {
                label: "Client 21",
                path: "/company/reseller/client21",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 9,
                branches: []
              },
              {
                label: "Client 22",
                path: "/company/reseller/client22",
                icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
                id: 10,
                branches: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Client",
        path: "/company/client",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 11,
        routeProps: {
          component: Client
        },
        branches: [
          {
            label: "Client 3",
            path: "/company/client/client3",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 12,
            branches: []
          },
          {
            label: "Client 4",
            path: "/company/client/client4",
            icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
            id: 13,
            branches: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Consumer",
        path: "/company/consumer",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        id: 14,
        routeProps: {
          component: Consumer
        },
        branches: []
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    label: "Contact Us",
    path: "/contactus",
    icon: <IoIcons.IoMdHelpCircle />,
    id: 20,
    routeProps: {
      render: () => <h1>About Us</h1>
    },
    branches: []
  }
];
```

Compute the routes

```
const routes = (data) =>
  data
    // include only data items with route props
    .filter(({ routeProps }) => !!routeProps)
    // recursively get "nested" routes, flatten to single array
    .flatMap(({ branches, id, path, routeProps }) => [
      ...routes(branches),
      { id, path, ...routeProps }
    ]);

const getRoutes = (data) =>
  routes(data)
    // sort more specific routes before less specific routes
    .sort((a, b) => b.path.localeCompare(a.path))
    // map to Route component
    .map(({ id, path, ...routeProps }) => (
      <Route key={id} path={path} {...routeProps} />
    ));
```

...

```
<Switch>
  {getRoutes(sidebarData)}
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-dynamic-router-for-nested-items-in-a-sidebar-with-multilevel-dropd]

Comment: Thank you for answering! But then I will still need to add path for every new branches and label, is there a way to not do that?

Comment: @Yuki You need to declare the paths you want to match and render *somewhere* so they can be matched and render routed content. If this isn't what you are wanting to do then it's completely unclear what you are trying to do or expecting. Can you clarify more precisely the use case you are trying to capture?